# Get a specific object from an object array in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

This is my object array and it is bound to a dropdownlist:

```
$scope.dropdownOptions = [{value: "0", name: 'No'}, {value: "1", name: 'Yes'}];
```

I want to return the corresponding "Name" depending on the selected "Value" in the dropdown through the following function. Right now I have hardcoded the return values.

```
$scope.getDropdownDisplayValue = function(_key){
    if(_key == "1")
      return "Yes";
    else if(_key == "0")
      return "No";
    else
      return "n/a";
  };
```

The problem is, if I modify the Names property of objects in that array I will have to come and change the return values of the above function as well. To Avoid that, I want to serach the object array and return the corresponding value. For example:

```
$scope.getDropdownDisplayValue = function(_key){
        if(_key == "1")
          return <get object.name where object.value == _key from dropdownOptions array>
        else if(_key == "0")
          return <get object.name where object.value == _key from dropdownOptions array>
        else
          return "n/a";
      };
```

I can write a custom function for that, but want to whether I can use something already available in AngularJS or JavaScript. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `filterFilter` service.

For example

```
app.controller('ExampleCtrl', ['$scope','filterFilter', function($scope, filterFilter) 
{

   $scope.dropdownOptions = [{value: "0", name: 'No'}, {value: "1", name: 'Yes'}];

   $scope.getDropdownDisplayValue = function(_key) {
      var objs = filterFilter($scope.dropdownOptions , {value: _key});
      if( objs.lenght > 0) {
        return objs[0].name;
      } else {
        return 'n/a';
      }
   };

 }]);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This worked for my problem perfectly. I did not know about filterFilter. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Is this you wanted?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/)

```
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope) {

  $scope.options = [
    { label: 'one', value: 1 },
    { label: 'two', value: 2 }
  ];

  // Although this object has the same properties as the one in $scope.options,
  // Angular considers them different because it compares based on reference
  $scope.incorrectlySelected = { label: 'two', value: 2 };

  // Here we are referencing the same object, so Angular inits the select box correctly
  $scope.correctlySelected = $scope.options[1];
});
```

index.html:

```
<select ng-model="incorrectlySelected"
            ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options">
        </select>
```

above is example from the angularJS official [website](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Here we are straightaway using the selected value from but my scenario was different. I wanted to get the value from dropdown and then later on refer to the object array and get the corresponding name from the same.